# Show Lebel and CheckBox on the same line inside my asp.net mvc core web application

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
 @Html.CheckBox("@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer", new { @class = "form-control" })  <label>@Model.SubmissionQuestion[i].Question</label>
```

currently the checkbox and the label will be shown on 2 separate lines, so can i force them to show on the same line?

here is the markup generated from the above:-

```
<input class="form-control" id="zModel_SubmissionQuestionSubmission_i__Answer" name="@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer" type="checkbox" value="true">
<label>Are you currently participating ?</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use [bootstrap's](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios-1) `form-check` instead of the `form-control`.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
<div class="form-check">

    @Html.CheckBox("@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer", new { @class = "form-check-input" })  <label class="form-check-label">@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Question</label>

</div>
```

Result:

[image]